# Is it possible to automate Chick Fil A One ordering process

Tags: automation

I work for a small delivery company in a college town and my boss brought up the idea of automating the order process for when a customer places an order for a restaurant like CFA using their own app (Chick Fil A One). I was wondering if this was even possible to begin with and if I could be pointed in the right direction. We are currently using [DeliveryLogic](http://www.deliverlogic.com/) as the backend software.

Comment: Yes, if you can think it can be done.  However this is such a large topic to discuss I think you're looking in the wrong forum.  You'll need to pull down some requirements of exactly what you want, then map those requirements out to piece out what you need, software, hardware, hosting, etc.  Being a small shop in a College Town maybe something like Azure or Amazon Web Services will fit your need.  Your costs scale with usage.

Comment: @DylanWright Thanks for the response! I can for sure map out some requirements and post them here if you are able to help with a more focused approach. I am very familiar with AWS services but the issue im facing with this project is that I have no idea where to begin. The CFA one app doesn't seem to have a public api and since its a mobile app I am not sure where to begin to automate it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I wish I had the bandwidth for this but I don't.  There are ton of sites out there that will help you out with this kind of stuff.  I would go to say a site like Free Code Camp and post in their forum.  I am sure someone will pick this is up.

Comment: On a side note in terms of a public API from CFA, you might want to create your own.  You're going to need a hosting service, this is where AWS comes in.  You create your server to host your own API, or Azure and then you need a host for your website as well.